# I want to hook the win32API ,but it doesn't work

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

I want to hook the `WriteFile` function .The target process is **notepad.exe** . But it doesn't work .
The code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<TlHelp32.h>


DEBUG_EVENT de;
FARPROC g_pfTargetAPIAddress;  //save the address of WriteFile function
BYTE g_ReadAPIBuffer;          //save the original content of the first byte of WriteFile function
BYTE g_WriteAPIBuffer=0xCC;    //change the first byte of WriteFile function to 0xCC , so that it can throw a breakpoint exception 
HANDLE g_hTargetProcessHandle;   //the handle of the target process (notepad.exe)
HANDLE g_hTargetThreadHandle;  //the main thread of the target process
DWORD g_dwTargetProcessId;      
DWORD g_dwTargetThreadId;


DWORD GetTargetProcess()    //get the id of the target process (notepad.exe)
{

PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
pe32.dwSize=sizeof(pe32);


HANDLE handle=::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS,0);
if(handle==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("get tool help handle error,the error code is:%u\n",GetLastError());
    system("PAUSE");
    return NULL;
}

BOOL bMore=::Process32First(handle,&pe32);
while(bMore)
{
    printf("the process name is:%ws\n",pe32.szExeFile);
    printf("the process id is %d\n",pe32.th32ProcessID);

    if(wcscmp(pe32.szExeFile,L"notepad.exe")==0)
    {
        return pe32.th32ParentProcessID;
    }

    bMore=::Process32Next(handle,&pe32);
}

return NULL;

}


BOOL OnProcessCreateDebug(LPDEBUG_EVENT de)
{

printf("now begin OnProcessCreateDebug\n");
g_hTargetProcessHandle=de->u.CreateProcessInfo.hProcess;
g_hTargetThreadHandle=de->u.CreateProcessInfo.hThread;
g_dwTargetThreadId=de->dwThreadId;

HMODULE hModule=::LoadLibrary(L"kernel32.dll");
if(hModule==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("get the api handle error ,the error code is :%u\n",GetLastError());
    system("PAUSE");
    return FALSE;
}

char cTargetAPIName[]="WriteFile";
g_pfTargetAPIAddress=::GetProcAddress(hModule,(LPCSTR)cTargetAPIName);
if(g_pfTargetAPIAddress==NULL)
{
    printf("the getprocaddress in onprocesscreatedebug failes,the error code is:%u",GetLastError());
    system("PAUSE");
    return FALSE;
}


BOOL bReadResult=::ReadProcessMemory(de->u.CreateProcessInfo.hProcess,g_pfTargetAPIAddress,&g_ReadAPIBuffer,sizeof(BYTE),NULL);
if(!bReadResult)
{
    printf("read the first byte of target api fails,the error code is :%u\n",GetLastError());
    system("PAUSE");
    return FALSE;
}



BOOL bWriteResult=::WriteProcessMemory(de->u.CreateProcessInfo.hProcess,g_pfTargetAPIAddress,&g_WriteAPIBuffer,sizeof(BYTE),NULL);
if(!bWriteResult)
{
    printf("write the first byte of target api fails,the error code is :%u\n",GetLastError());
    system("PAUSE");
    return FALSE;

}

printf("now finish OnProcessCreateDebugEvent\n");

return TRUE;

}


BOOL OnExceptionDebugEvent(LPDEBUG_EVENT de)
{

printf("now go into the OnExceptionDebugEvent just now\n"); 
PEXCEPTION_RECORD per=&de->u.Exception.ExceptionRecord;

if(per->ExceptionCode==EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT)
{

    printf("now it is in the first if\n");

    if(per->ExceptionAddress==g_pfTargetAPIAddress)
    {

        printf("now has entered the OnExceptionDebugEvent\n");


        if(!WriteProcessMemory(g_hTargetProcessHandle,g_pfTargetAPIAddress,&g_WriteAPIBuffer,sizeof(BYTE),NULL))
        {
            printf("onexecption write the first byte of target api fails,the error code is :%u\n",GetLastError());
            system("PAUSE");
            return FALSE;
        }


        CONTEXT con;
        con.ContextFlags=CONTEXT_CONTROL;
        ::GetThreadContext(g_hTargetThreadHandle,&con);

        DWORD dwWriteFileBufferAddress;
        if(!::ReadProcessMemory(g_hTargetProcessHandle,(LPCVOID)(con.Esp+0x8),&dwWriteFileBufferAddress,sizeof(DWORD),NULL))
        {
            printf("read the  the lpBaseAddress of target api  fails,the error code is :%u\n",GetLastError());
            system("PAUSE");
            return FALSE;
        }


        printf("now after esp+8\n");

        DWORD dwSizeOfBuffer;
        if(!::ReadProcessMemory(g_hTargetProcessHandle,(LPCVOID)(con.Esp+0x10),&dwSizeOfBuffer,sizeof(DWORD),NULL))
        {
            printf("read the lpBuffer of target api fails,the error code is :%u\n",GetLastError());
            system("PAUSE");
            return FALSE;
        }


        LPBYTE lpBuffer=(LPBYTE)malloc(dwSizeOfBuffer+1);
        LPBYTE lppointer=lpBuffer;
        for(int i=0;i<=dwSizeOfBuffer;i++)
        {
            *lppointer=0x1;
            lppointer++;
        }
        *lppointer=0x0;

        if(!::WriteProcessMemory(g_hTargetProcessHandle,(LPVOID)dwWriteFileBufferAddress,lpBuffer,dwSizeOfBuffer+1,NULL))
        {
            printf("overridewrite the  buffer of target api fails,the error code is :%u\n",GetLastError());
            system("PAUSE");
            return FALSE;
        }

        free(lpBuffer);


        con.Eip=(DWORD)g_pfTargetAPIAddress;
        SetThreadContext(g_hTargetThreadHandle,&con);

        ContinueDebugEvent(g_dwTargetProcessId,g_dwTargetThreadId,DBG_CONTINUE);


        printf("now after the ContinueDebugEvent\n");

        Sleep(0);

        BYTE byte=0xcc;
        if(!::WriteProcessMemory(g_hTargetProcessHandle,g_pfTargetAPIAddress,&byte,sizeof(BYTE),NULL))
        {
            printf("rewrite the first byte of target api fails,the error code is :%u\n",GetLastError());
            system("PAUSE");
            return FALSE;
        }

    }

    else 
        {
            printf("not enter the second if\n");
        }
}


else printf("not enter the first if\n");

return TRUE;
}


BOOL HookAPI()
{
while(WaitForDebugEvent(&de,INFINITE))
{
    if(de.dwDebugEventCode==CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT)
    {
        if(!OnProcessCreateDebug(&de)) return FALSE;

    }


    else if(de.dwDebugEventCode==EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT)
    {
        printf("now it is going to call the OnExceptionDebugEvent\n");
        if(!OnExceptionDebugEvent(&de)) return FALSE;
    }
    else if(de.dwDebugEventCode==EXIT_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT)
    {
        break;
    }


    ::ContinueDebugEvent(de.dwProcessId,de.dwThreadId,DBG_CONTINUE);

}
return TRUE;
}


int main()
{
g_dwTargetProcessId=GetTargetProcess();
if(g_dwTargetProcessId==NULL)
{
    printf("the value of dProcessId is null\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return -1;
}


BOOL b=DebugActiveProcess(g_dwTargetProcessId);
if(!b)
{
    printf("DebugActiveProcess fails,the last error is : %u\n",GetLastError());
    system("PAUSE");
    return -1;
}

HookAPI();

return 0;
}
```

I want to hook the `WriteFile` function , and it changes the first byte of `WriteFile` function to `0xCC` , but it doesn't work . I can save file as normal using **notepad.exe** . I guess the `0xCC` cannot throw a breakpoint exception . 
Anyone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: Looks like you are confident  `notepad.exe` is 32-bits, but nowadays this is rarely true. Hooking APIs in 64-bit programs is somewhat different.

Comment: AFAIK `notepad.exe` maps the file you are editing into memory, so it probably does not use `WriteFile` very often.

Comment: @Havenard I am just studying and this program I only run on the 32 bit Windows Xp sp3

Answer (score 1):

This code could be compiled only in `x86` environment, since `CONTEXT` structure will have entirely different set of fields for `x64` processors. Since `x64` operating systems are prevailing now, `notepad.exe` is most likely a `x64` application, so your `x86` application would be unable to even attach to it. `DebugActiveProcess` will return `FALSE`, with `GetLastError` == `ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED`. If we ignore this bittness thing for a moment (or assume that  notepad is a `x86` app), there are some thing to improve in your code.

First. This error validation code is invalid:

```
HMODULE hModule = ::LoadLibrary(L"kernel32.dll");
if (hModule == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("get the api handle error ,the error code is :%u\n", GetLastError());
    system("PAUSE");
    return FALSE;
}
```

`LoadLibrary` returns `NULL` on error, `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is -1, so your error handler would never be invoked. While `kernel32.dll` absence is quite impossible, this should be considered for other dlls.

Second. You could not debug other process if you could not open its handle with `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` access mask. Setting `SE_DEBUG_NAME` privilege could also help. To enable this privilege your account should have administrator rights (or this privilege should be enabled in the group policy). Even if account has `SE_DEBUG_NAME` it should be explicitly requested by the application. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa446619(v=vs.85).aspx) MSDN example for the details.

Third. Dll code pages are protected from writing. So you have to use `VirtualProtectEx` to change memory protection to the `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE`

Fourth. You can not assume, that the same dll will have the same load address in the different processes. Dll could be rebased on the load if there is a conflict with some other dll base load address. Also all modern Windows OS since Windows Vista have a security feature called Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR). So you have to enumerate dlls in the target process using ToolHelp API instead just calling `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: `WriteProcessMemory` actualy does change the page protection (temporarily).

Comment: I run this program on Windows XP sp3 , and it has not ASLR . And I think ASLR only reload the base address of  the dll and other process when restart the computer . But all the base address of the dll is the same in the system .